# Ubuntu automatically selects the wrong option when I plug my headphones

Tags: sound, headphones, bug-reporting

I am using the latest Ubuntu 18.04 on a Dell G3 laptop and having an odd behaviour.
My sound on the headphones doesn't work sometimes, even though I hear some clips when plugin in (showing that phone and hardware are working).

I looked for solutions online, installed packages and run several commands. The only one that works for me is typing `alsactl restore` once in a while. However it is not guaranteed that it will always work.

Looking around I found an interest thing.
On the input tab, when I select the headset option I have no audio but if I change it my audio comes back. This behaviour is coherent with my setup, since I have a headphone, not a headset. The problem is that the headset option is selected automatically when I plug in my headphone.

Does anyone know why this could be happening?

[image]